# chrome console.log support format specifier on android

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i would like to use console.log with format specifier like this:

```
window.console.log("%s has %d points", "SAM", 100);
```

i have added above line in java script on chrome on android. but current output is  <%s has %d points>.
expected output is "SAM has 100 points"
when i run below in chrome desktop expected value is correct. what is problem in android version of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but one of versions which you can use

```
var nativeConsole = console.log;
console.log = function(){
    var toPrint = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\\{'+(i - 1)+'\\}', 'gi');
        toPrint = toPrint.replace(regexp, arguments[i]);
    }
    nativeConsole.apply(this, new Array(toPrint));
}
```

so you can call it

```
console.log("{0} test {1}", "1", 2)
```

Comment: why dont we can escape Format specifiers (%s, %d) in this case?